# Passing a JS var from AJAX response to Twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, octobercms

I am trying to pass a Javascript `var = value` that I receive from an Ajax response to the twig `|trans` filter so I can translate the strings.

`{{('makler.realestate::lang.tip_neprem.' ~ value)|trans}}` doesn't work, because value returns empty.

```
  $.each( tipi_nepremicnin, function( key, value ) {
    $(select_input)
    .append(
    "<option value='" + value + "'>" 
    + '{{('makler.realestate::lang.tip_neprem.' ~ value)|trans}}'  
    + "</option>").removeAttr("disabled"
    );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

You've got two solutions :

1. Translate your content in PHP then pass it to ajax response
2. Use [Bazing js translation bundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) so you can translate JS variables

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you :)